# Do people really become more reserved in cities, if so why?

Tags: sociology

> The rapid tempo of life in a city was such that people needed a "protective organ" to insulate them from the external and internal stimuli. According to Simmel, the metropolitan "reaction with his head instead his heart", he erects a rational barrier of cultivated in difference..
> pg,205, The sociology book

Is this in line with modern psychology? If so with what mechanisms are the above mentioned nature's developed?

Comment: How is reaction with your head rather than your heart an action of a reserved person? I am confused

Comment: Not reserved but reactive.